# Uniquely intserting values into priority queue C++

Tags: c++, c++11, data-structures

I wrote the following code for inserting unique values into a data structure from which I can retrieve values in a sorted order(in the following code I have used priority queue for this purpose, however, any other data structure like sorted vector can also be used). However, I found the following code to be extremely slow given that I am inserting 1 million values into my priority queue. Can someone please help me understand how can I improve the code given below:

```
class unique_queue1 {
//private:
public:    
    std::priority_queue<std::pair<vector<int>, double>, vector<std::pair<vector<int>, double> >, CompareClass1 > m_queue;
    std::set<vector<int> > m_set;
//public:
    bool push(const pair<vector<int>, double> & t) {
        if (m_set.insert(t.first).second) {
            m_queue.push(t);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    void pop() {
        assert(!m_queue.empty());
        const std::pair<vector<int>, double>& val = front();

        std::set<vector<int> >::iterator it = m_set.find(val.first);
        assert(it != m_set.end());

        m_set.erase(it);
        m_queue.pop();
    }

    const pair<vector<int>, double>& front() const {
        return m_queue.top();
    }    

    bool empty() const{
        return m_queue.empty();
    }
};
```

Comment: If you need the `set` then you don't need the priority queue.  The `set` always has the first item available for easy access.  You don't need the extra work of `find` to match the first item in the `set` and you don't need the priority queue at all.

Comment: @JSF I am a little new to c++. If possible, I'll be really thankful if you can help me with a code a little bit. As being new to C++, I am unable to understand what you are saying. In my code I kept "set", so that values (vector<int>) inserted into priority queue are unique

Comment: How much faster do you need?  Changing the `set` to do the entire job and eliminating the priority queue should make the code nearly two times faster.  But if you need more improvement than that, you need a more basic redesign.  To make the `set` do the entire job, it must hold the same objects and have the same comparison function you now use for the priority queue (instead of just most of the object and default comparison).

Comment: @JSF Thanks for your response. If it is possible to make the code faster with basic redesign, then that will be great :) Additonally I read on stackoverflow that vectors are faster than set? Is it true? If yes, can I somehow make use of vectors here?

Comment: Vectors are faster than sets for _some use cases_. Whether this is one, you need to test.

Comment: Vectors are not faster than sets for maintaining a collection in which you need to detect and suppress duplicates.  If a more basic redesign is needed, that does not just mean redesign this class.  It means redesign the program containing this class so that it has easier requirements for whatever takes the place of this class.

Comment: @JSF I found using "perf" tool, that this class is the bottleneck. So, perhaps , just this class needs to be redesigned

Comment: When you insert into each of those containers, you copy the entire `vector<int>`.  Copying that once rather than twice could be a big part of making this class nearly twice as fast.  But no redesign limited to this class can do better than that.  Maybe the rest of the program could be redesigned so those vectors don't need to be copied even once.  Without considering the whole program, you can't make that kind of improvement to this class.

Comment: @JSF vector<int> are small, their size is atmost 10. Therefore I think insertion of such small vectors will not make a difference but please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Maybe your compare functor is terrible.  You didn't show its source code.  It ought to be inlined by the compiler, so the profiler ought to report the performance cost of that functor as part of this class.  So that could fit the "perf" tool results you mentioned.

Comment: @JSF Yes you are right that could be the case. If I have to substitute the code for my priority_queue with "set", then how can I do the same. I guess using a priority_queue and set are redundant. But I am not getting how to keep just set

Answer (score 2):

Since you want to enforce uniqueness, you really just need the set.

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>

using namespace std;
class unique_queue1
{
public:
    using value_type = std::pair<vector<int>, double>;
    std::set<value_type, CompareClass1> m_set;

    bool push(const value_type& t) {
        return m_set.insert(t).second;
    }

    void pop() {
        m_set.erase(m_set.begin());
    }

    const value_type& front() const {
        return *m_set.begin();
    }

    bool empty() const{
        return m_set.empty();
    }
};
```

Now, unless you do some additional magic in that class of yours, you could of course just replace the whole thing with just the set...

Other than that, your introduction text reads like you actually want to fill a container with data first, and only after filling it completely, you want to obtain unique entries in sorted order.

I suggest you try pushing everything into a vector, then use algorithms `std::sort` and `std::unique` and `std::reverse`, then retrieve the data using `pop_back`. I am pretty sure that this will be quite a bit faster than using `set`.

Here's how this would look like (untested):

```
class unique_queue1
{
public:
  using value_type = std::pair<vector<int>, double>;
  std::vector<value_type> values;

  void push_back(const value_type& t)
  {
    return values.push_back(t);
  }

  // Must be called between push_back and (pop or front)
  void prepare()
  {
    sort(values.begin(),
         values.end(),
         CompareClass1());  // Maybe use lambdas for comparison
    erase(unique(values.begin(), 
                 values.end(),
                 CompareClass2()),  // Need a comparator for equality, again,
                                    // you might want to use a lambda
          values.end());  

    reverse(values.begin(), values.end());
  }

  void pop()
  {
    values.pop_back();
  }

  const value_type& front() const
  {
    return values.back();
  }

  bool empty() const
  {
    return values.empty();
  }
};
```

Comment: but for the set solution, it gives me an error:  error: no matching function for call to ‘std::set<std::vector<std::pair<std::vector<int>, double> >, CompareClass1>::insert(const std::vector<int>&)’
         return m_set.insert(t.first).second;
                                    ^

Comment: I did not run the compiler, just showed the idea in general. I updated the code to compile (although I do not know what your Compare is doing, so you might still experience some trouble).

Comment: I am afraid its still giving me the same error...seems like insert is not working. I am using gcc-4.9 compiler with c++11

Comment: Well, you need to create a minimal piece of code that people can experiment with. It should contain all required includes, classes, a main function. Otherwise, it will be hard to figure out what is going wrong in your code.

Comment: You copied a `vector` from the priority queue that you don't want.  Change the `value_type` definition to `using value_type = std::pair<vector<int>, double>;`

Comment: @JSF Ah, nicely spotted! Corrected the value_type.